# Elixir: How to sort a list of (naive) datetimes?

Tags: sorting, datetime, elixir

I have a list of NaiveDateTimes and I want to get the most recent one. What's the easiest way to sort a list of DateTimes / NaiveDateTimes?

I know it's unsafe to use Elixir's standard sorting rules, since it compares terms structurally rather than looking at the meaning of the dates:

```
# UNSAFE / returns entries in incorrect order:
[~N[2020-02-29 10:00:01], ~N[2020-03-11 10:20:00], ~N[2020-03-15 10:00:00]] |> Enum.sort
# => [~N[2020-03-11 10:20:00], ~N[2020-03-15 10:00:00], ~N[2020-02-29 10:00:01]]
```

Answer (score 14):

Since `v1.9` [`Enum.sort/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html?#sort/2-sorting-structs) accepts a module that exports `compare/2`.

```rb
Enum.sort(naive_date_times, NaiveDateTime)
Enum.sort(dates, Date)
```

Answer (score 7):

If all values are DateTime (with timezone), you can use `DateTime.compare`:

```
sorted = Enum.sort(datetimes, & DateTime.compare(&1, &2) != :gt)
```

If all values are NaiveDateTime (no timezone data), you can use `NaiveDateTime.compare`:

```
sorted = Enum.sort(datetimes, & NaiveDateTime.compare(&1, &2) != :gt)
```

And if you're lazy and/or have Timex installed, you can use `Timex.diff` which will infer UTC timezone for any NaiveDateTimes:

```
sorted = Enum.sort(datetimes, & Timex.diff(&1, &2) < 0)
```

Comment: While absolutely correct, this answer is a bit obsoleted since `v1.9`, check my answer for details.